# How to suppress certain logs in JBoss?

Tags: logging, jboss

How can we suppress logs in Jboss, related to certain Error which are harmless?

For example I want to suppress logs which contains the text '/sass'

Comment: What version of JBoss EAP or WildFly are you using? If it's EAP 7.x or WildFly you can have a look at log filters https://docs.wildfly.org/19/Admin_Guide.html#logging-filters.

Comment: Its JBoss 7.1.1

Comment: It's not well documented for JBoss AS 7.x as it's changed since then, but you can look at the filter on the model https://wildscribe.github.io/JBoss%20AS7/7.1.1/subsystem/logging/logger/index.html. You'd likely want a `match` filter which uses regex.

Answer (score 0):

You can change logging level for certain packages. Supported logging levels are as following TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, and FATAL, OFF.
Example1:

```
<logger category="com.yourpackage">
      <level name="FATAL"/>
</logger>
<logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
     <level name="ERROR"/>
</logger>
```

Also you can write some logs into file other than server.log using different log handler. In the following example that I write clustering logs into server_clustering.log file.
Example2:

```
<periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE_CLUSTERING" autoflush="true">
            <formatter>
                <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
            </formatter>
            <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server_clustering.log"/>
            <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
            <append value="true"/>
        </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
        <logger category="org.jboss.as.clustering" use-parent-handlers="false">
            <level name="INFO"/>
            <handlers>
                <handler name="FILE_CLUSTERING"/>
            </handlers>
        </logger>
```

I don't think there is no such feature that excludes logs containing certain text. Hope it helps.